# Two select tags in one Form, POST method only getting one select tag's value

Tags: php, post, select, isset

I have a form with two select tags, and after submitting, I only receive back one select tag's value.

My two selects are select pokemonRegion and pokemonType
Only getting pokemonRegion

```
    echo("<form method=\"POST\">");
    echo ("<select name=\"region\" > 
    <option id=\"region\" selected=\"selected\">Choose Region</option>");
    foreach($regions as $option){
       echo ("<option value=\"$option\">$option</option>");
    }
    echo("</select>");
    echo("<br><br><br>");
    //select pokemon type
    echo ("<select name=\"pokemonType\" style=\"text-align: center\">  
    <option id=\"region\" selected=\"selected\">Choose Type</option>");
    foreach($types as $option){
       echo ("<option value=\"$option\">$option</option>");
    }
    echo("</select>");
    echo("<br><br><br><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" />");
    echo("</form>");
    echo("</div>");

    //grab pokemon from pokedex database
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $type = $_POST['pokemonType'];
        $region = $_POST['region'];
        echo("<br> You chose $region and $pokemonType");
    }
```

Example: after I select johto (region) and water (type), I get "You chose Johto and     " blank

Comment: `$type = $POST['pokemontype'];` and then `and $pokemontype");`?  You need to use the same variable!

Comment: While researching, I learned I should have architected my code differently -> as in made an html file, and then called a form tag like this -> <form action="pokemon.php" method=POST> ...</form> and put all my php code there, instead of having so many echos for all my html content here.

Anyways thats just a side note, as I am still learning. If anyone has an example php project that supports what I am thinking, let me know.

Comment: use `$_POST['pokemonType']` not `$POST['pokemonType']`. And please write html and php separately. This looks so bad. But please read how to use `PHP` here - https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Thank you nigel, 
I used
$type = $_POST['pokemontype']; and then and $pokemontype");

its 5am, I spent too much time on a variable mismatch, sorry about that ='(

Should be $type = $_POST['pokemontype']; and then and $type");